# Convert Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream to System.IO.Stream

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

How can I convert `Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream` to `System.IO.Stream`?

I'm using a C# library which accepts `System.IO.Stream` as input, but when I open files in Metro I get `Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way is to call [`AsStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.windowsruntimestreamextensions.asstream.aspx).

Comment: There is no `AsStream` method for WP8 although it exist for WinRT.

Comment: don't forget to `using System.IO;`

Answer (score 7):

You can convert `Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream` to a `byte[]` and then convert `byte[]` to a `System.IO.Stream`.

**Byte[] from IRandomAccessStream**

```
        var file = await new FileOpenPicker().PickSingleFileAsync();
        var fStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

        var reader = new DataReader(fStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
        var bytes = new byte[fStream.Size];
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fStream.Size);
        reader.ReadBytes(bytes);
```

**Stream from Byte[]**

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```